# Timer speeds up after every run

Tags: java, android, timer

I am making a simple image viewer for Android. I need to implement a slideshow as well. I am sort of done, except I have an annoying bug. When I run the slideshow ( at the press of a button) it works. But when I cancel the slideshow and run it again (same button) the slideshow speeds up.

EDIT: Added fixed code, look at the comments in the slideshow part of the code to see what needed fixing

```
   package csc2002.imageviewer;
   //imports

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    static Timer timer = new Timer();
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    int checker=0;
    int start,delay = 1800;
    boolean toggle;


    private static Integer[] imageIds = { //Hard coded array
        R.raw.bulbasaur,R.raw.switch_brain,R.raw.quote,R.raw.victory,R.raw.penguins,R.raw.jellyfish,R.raw.koala};

    private static final int IMAGE_COUNT = imageIds.length;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Called when the app is opened

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);       
        Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button slideshow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
        slideshow.setOnClickListener(this);
        displayImage();
    }

    // responsible for displaying the image and the name of the image.
    private void displayImage() { // Displays the image on the screen according the the current array index

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
        imgView.setImageResource(imageIds[arrayIndex]);
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        text.setText(imageIds[arrayIndex]);
    }

    // This method allows the cycling of images

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==(R.id.backButton)){ //Back button
            arrayIndex--;

            if(arrayIndex==-1){
                arrayIndex = IMAGE_COUNT-1;
            }
            displayImage();
        }

        else if (v.getId()==(R.id.nextButton)){ //NextButton
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        if(arrayIndex==IMAGE_COUNT){
            arrayIndex = 0;
        }
        displayImage();

        if (v.getId()==R.id.slideButton){ //Slideshow button
            Button slideshow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
            toggle^= true;
            if(toggle==true){
                slideshow.setText("Stop Slideshow");
            }
            else{slideshow.setText("Start Slideshow");}
        }
        // Slideshow functionality

        if(toggle==true){
            //timer=new Timer(); //this was added in the correct solution(This was the main problem).
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(toggle==true){
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                arrayIndex++;
                                if(arrayIndex==IMAGE_COUNT){
                                    arrayIndex=0;
                                }

                                displayImage();
                            }
                        });
                    }  
                }

            },start,delay);

        }
        else if(toggle==false){
            //timer.cancel(); This was added to correct the solution
        }
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) { //This saves data when the app is rotated
        outState.putInt("KEY", arrayIndex);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle save){ //Restores Data after interruption
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(save);
        arrayIndex = save.getInt("KEY");
        displayImage();
    }


}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29

The TimerTask class does not offer real-time guarantees: it schedules tasks using the Object.wait(long) method.

Comment: Are you adding the timer event to your scheduler on every button toggle?  If so, you have multiple timer events occurring simultaneously which would look like a speed up to you.

Comment: +1 for not tagging this as Android.

Comment: Try and use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead.

Comment: Leave these `//end ...` comments, thats madness o.o

Comment: @Tansir1 Yes, toggle changes from true to false and back whenever I click the slidehow button, so this might well be happening. How do I fix this?

Comment: In future questions, you can remove the import statements for brevity.  They're all for standard Java or Android classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems with a project I did a couple of years ago. Granted, I was using a `Timer` object, but here's a couple things I did to fix the problem:

- Make sure you explicitly stop the timer.
- Reinitialize the timer, overwriting the original timer.

If these suggestions don't work, try posting more code.

**EDIT**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //...
    if (v.getId()==R.id.slideButton){ //Slideshow button
        toggle^= true;
        if(toggle==true){
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(/*Whatever TimerTask you had here before*/);         
        }
        else{
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }//end if(slide button)
}//end onClick()
```

By doing it this way, the timer is only started or ended when the toggle button is clicked. The timer is created when the button is clicked, and canceled when it is clicked again. There should never be two active timers at the same time. I'm not really sure how well this will adapt to the code you have now, but it should work with the code you had the first time.

Comment: As Tasnsir1 said, toggle changes from true to false and back whenever I click the slideshow button, so multiple timer events might be triggering. How do I change this? timer.cancel() does not work.

Comment: An unfortunate different between our projects is that I was using `javax.swing.Timer`, so our solutions might be slightly different. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) for your timer indicates that once `timer.cancel()` is called, the timer will not take any more `TimerTask`s, so there shouldn't be any new timer events after the current one stops. I think we need to see the broader context of the code you posted. Particularly, when is the posted code used, how do you change the value of `toggle`, and where was `timer.cancel()`?

Comment: Answer updated. I'm not sure if your current code can be adapted to use the ideas of my code, or if it can be replaced by my code. Either way, my code should illustrate the cause of the increasing number of timer events that you experienced.

Comment: Thanks so much. your answer was spot on ( I reverted back to timer). I think the timer = new Timer(); was all that I needed. Again thank you, God bless.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help. And remember, if you're sure someone's answer worked for you, make sure you mark it as the answer ;)

Comment: And if this is the answer, could you also edit the question, so that it contains the context of your code like it does now, but using the `TimerTask` like it did before? That should make it clearer for anyone else who sees your question.